# how can i get a boolean answer to see if the index of one dataframe contains all elements of columns in another dataframe but not in the same order

Tags: python, pandas

I have subsetted a dataframe whose index is present as values (strings) in another dataframe as follows:

```
df = df1[df1.index.isin(df2['column_name'])]
```

this works without issue however the order of the index in the df is different to that of `df2['column_name']`

this is understandable and also fine as i dont care for the order of the new df. however as a sanity check I would like to be sure that the new dataframe indexes exactly match those of the column names in df2 (again, not order but just that the subsetting works correctly)

unfortunately, `df.index.equals(df2['column_name')` returns False as it expects the order to also be the same.

Is there a way of checking that values match without worrying about the order?

reproducible example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]),index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], columns=['values'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']), index=range(3), columns=['column_name'])

df = df1[df1.index.isin(df2['column_name'])]
```

thank you

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: answer updated - I need to check in the new df that the index contains values from column_name of df2 - in real life, the orders are not obeyed, so i need to check for equality - the closest i have got is by using.isin..however I get am array of booleans where i only need one boolean.. either True or False

Comment: This is just a thought- you could merge and check if the len() of the dataframe is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test values for subsets - without ordering is possible by:

```
print (set(df2['column_name']).issubset(df1.index))
True

print (df2['column_name'].isin(df1.index).all())
True
```

Comment: no, sorry, i dont need to merge - the subsetting has been done fine, as a sanity check i need to see if the index of the new dataframe matches that of the 'column_name' column in df2

Comment: @user9317212 - Can you check now?

Comment: this works, thank you! can you explain .issubset() and how this looks for equality? thanks

Comment: @user9317212 - column are converted to sets and then tested by `issubset` if all values of column are in `df1.index`. Similar with `isin`, then is test if all values are Trues by `all`

Comment: fantastic, thank you!